# GWT development and Design Patterns

Tags: java, gwt, design-patterns

What patterns are  the most popular used by experienced programmers for development on GWT?
 I have heard that the effective development on this framework often has to use different design patterns.
I would like to know more about this. If it is possible with a brief explanation, example or link.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use MVP: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture. It's great for organizing larger projects. MVP is mainly concerned with client-side organization.

You can use this in conjunction with Activities and Places to manage View history: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces

Your server-side patterns will generally follow the standard Java servlet model. If you use Hibernate/Objectify or some similar ORM solution, look into GWT RequestFactory.

Comment: Ray Ryan's 2009 GWT architecture video is a little dated, but still has some good suggestions.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM